# 'class_name' has no attribute 'attribute_name'

Tags: python

look at this code plz :there is rules,In every instance the_oldets must refresh, Live is a abstract class

```
class Live(object):
    _the_oldest = 0

    def __init__(self,age,name):
        self.age=age
        self.name=name

    @classmethod
    def the_oldest(cls):
        if Live._the_oldest < cls.age:
            Live._the_oldest=cls.age

    @staticmethod
    def Print(): 
        print(Live._the_oldest)


class Dog(Live):

    def __init__(self,name,age):
        super().__init__(age,name)
        super().the_oldest()



class Cat(Live):
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        super().__init__(age,name)
        super().the_oldest()
```

there is error :

```
>>> db=Dog('doberman',12)
AttributeError: type object 'Dog' has no attribute 'age'
```

I have changed code but nothing changed:

```
class Live(object):
    _the_oldest = 0

    def __init__(self):
        the_oldets(self)

    @classmethod
    def the_oldets(cls):
        if Live._the_oldest < cls.age:
            Live._the_oldest=cls.age

    @staticmethod
    def Print(): 
        print(Live._the_oldest)



class Dog(Live):
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.age=age
        self.name=name



class Cat(Live):
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.age=age
        self.name=name
```

result:

```
>>> db=Dog('doberman',12)
>>> db.the_oldets()
AttributeError: type object 'Dog' has no attribute 'age'
```

why it happend !?  and how fix that ?

Comment: Please edit your previous question into shape to have it re-opened. Don't just repost to see what parts are not too broad (you are still asking multiple questions in one post, don't do that please). If you continue to post questions that end up being closed you run the risk of being question-banned.

Comment: I have delete that !

Comment: ok sorry ! I have edit it .just one question .

Comment: What `the_oldest` should return? The oldest live thing or for Dog it should be the oldest dog and for cat a cat etc. ?

Comment: yes how can do that ?

Answer (score 1):

The error results from `cls.age` in:

```
@classmethod
def the_oldest(cls):
    if Live._the_oldest < cls.age:
        Live._the_oldest = cls.age
```

The problem is that the class `cls` doesn't have the property `age` that the instances do. If that function was not a class method, it could be written as:

```
def the_oldest(self):
    if Live._the_oldest < self.age:
        Live._the_oldest = self.age
```

But that function updates the oldest incorrectly as it does it would only update it to the object that it was called on if it was older. Rather as implied in the question the goal is for `Live._the_oldest` to contain the age of the oldest created subclass of Live so the update has to be done at the time of the creation of those instances and not at the time when `the_oldest` is called hence the following.

Update the oldest in `__init__` where it has access to the instance:

```
class Live(object):
    _the_oldest = 0

    def __init__(self,age,name):
        self.age=age
        self.name=name
        if Live._the_oldest < self.age:
            Live._the_oldest = self.age

    @staticmethod
    def the_oldest():
        return Live._the_oldest

    @staticmethod
    def Print(): 
        print(Live._the_oldest)
```

Comment: It works, but what is diffrence? why my code have error ?

Comment: Your class `Live` doesn't have an attribute called `age`. So when you ask for `cls.age` in a classmethod it will crash.

Comment: when I use age , cls = Dog or Cat  class - > def the_oldets(cls) . is not ? and I am chcking  cls.age not Live.age .

Comment: this def the_oldest(cls) dosnot need to be a @classmethod ! look at this : class Live(object):
    _the_oldest = 0

    def __init__(self,age,name):
        self.age=age
        self.name=name
        if Live._the_oldest < self.age:
            Live._the_oldest = self.age

    staticmethod
    def the_oldest():
        return Live._the_oldest

    staticmethod
    def Print(): 
        print(Live._the_oldest)

Comment: Quite so, but I didn't need multiple lines of code in a comment to be told that.